# Adding a hash that has an array in Ruby and adding to that array

Tags: arrays, ruby, nested, hash-of-hashes, ruby-hash

Hello all I'm new and I've been searching and can't find a clear answer to this question, I'm hoping this summarizes it:

```
a = {:a1 => "a1", :b1 => [] }
```

how would I add `:c1` to the `a` hash and make it another hash, leading to an array, and add values to that array?  I would like the return of the `a` hash to resemble:

```
=> {:a1 => "a1", :b1 => [], :c1 => {c2 => [0, 1]}
```

Comment: Does "make it another hash" mean "add data to hash `a` by altering it" or does it mean "create a new hash that's `a` plus some other data"?

Answer (score 3):

### Merging Hashes

One option among others is to use [Hash#merge!](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.2/Hash.html#method-i-merge-21). For example:

```rb
a = {:a1=>"a1", :b1=>[]}
a.merge!({:c1=>{:c2=>[0, 1]}})
#=> {:a1=>"a1", :b1=>[], :c1=>{:c2=>[0, 1]}}
```

Note that while parenthesis are often optional in Ruby, they're needed with Hash literals and #merge! to ensure the Hash to be merged is treated as an argument instead of a block by the parser/interpreter.

If you'd prefer to return a new Hash with the merged elements, then use [Hash#merge](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.2/Hash.html#method-i-merge) instead. This will leave the original *a* untouched, while returning a copy of *a* merged with your Hash-literal argument.

Comment: Note: There's no need for `{ ... }` inside of a method call, the last argument can be an implicit hash or keyword arguments. That is `f({ x: y, ... })` is equivalent to `f(x: y, ...)`.

Answer (score 2):

In multiple steps:

```
a = { :a1 => "a1", :b1 => [] }
a[:c1] = {}
a[:c1][:c2] = []
a[:c1][:c2] << 0
a[:c1][:c2] << 1

a #=> { :a1 => "a1", :b1 => [], :c1 => { :c2 => [0, 1] } }
```

Or in one step:

```
a = { :a1 => "a1", :b1 => [] }
a[:c1] = { c2: [0, 1] }

a #=> { :a1 => "a1", :b1 => [], :c1 => { :c2 => [0, 1] } }
```

Comment: This alters the `a` hash, if that's acceptable. If the intent is to make a new one, you'd have to at least `dup` it.